# Django Python m2m_change does not work when removing the relation

Tags: python, django, save

I am writing a project related to courses. However, the save() does not work when I use Django admin to add CourseSession. But when I edit it and then save, it will work. Please help me. Followings are class CourseSession and Course. What I am doing here is to update instructors of each course automatically when related course session is added.（update: I have used the m2m_change function but it wont work when removing course session）

```
def course_session_instructor_changed(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
superCourse = instance.course
superCourse.instructors.clear()


course_session_set = superCourse.course_session.all()
for each_course_session in course_session_set:
    # add instructor
    if action=="post_add":
        instructors = each_course_session.instructors.all()
        for instructor in instructors:
            if not instructor in superCourse.instructors.all():
                superCourse.instructors.add(instructor)

    # remove instructor
    elif action=="pre_remove" :
        if not each_course_session == instance:
            instructors = each_course_session.instructors.all()
            for instructor in instructors:
                if not instructor in superCourse.instructors.all():
                    superCourse.instructors.add(instructor)

superCourse.save()

m2m_changed.connect(course_session_instructor_changed,     sender=CourseSession.instructors.through)

class CourseSession(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', related_name='course_session')

    instructors = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'instructor_course_session')
    enrollment = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'course_enrollment')    
    start = models.DateField()
    # Weeks of duration
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    # capacity of the session
    max_cap = models.IntegerField()

    questionSet = models.ManyToManyField(QuestionSet, blank=True, null=True, related_name='session_questionSet')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Session')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Sessions')
        get_latest_by = "start"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.instructors.all())+unicode(self.course)+unicode(self.start)

    def is_started(self):
        return date.today()> self.start

    def is_expired(self):
        length = timedelta(days = self.duration*7)
        return self.start+length< date.today()

    def get_enrollment(self):
        return self.enrollment.count()




**class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Course Name'),max_length=256)
    # Simple Introduction
    brief_intro = models.CharField(_('Brief Intro'),max_length=1024)
    intro = models.TextField()
    learning_obj = models.TextField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'course_creator')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'course/covers/')
    institute = models.ForeignKey('Institute', related_name='institute_courses')
    workload = models.IntegerField()
    assignments = models.IntegerField()
    exams = models.IntegerField()   
    knowledge_tree_root = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='knowledge_tree_root')
    instructors = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='courses', null=True, blank=True)

    #tree_root = models.ForeignKey('Topic')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Course')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Courses')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work the first time, as many-to-many fields can't be set until the instance has been saved once (since they're saved in a separate table, and have to have an ID to link to). So the admin doesn't set the values until after the save.

Rather than override save, you probably want to use the [`m2m_changed` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed).

Comment: I have written a m2m_change function. It does work at first time. However, when I remove a course session, it would not be triggered. Could you tell me why?